# Visual Flow - Unable to pass multiple selected values from one screen to next screen

Tags: visual-workflow, flow, visual-flows

I want to create a visual flow wherein there will be two screens. On first screen I want to select few fields(only name of fields will display in multiselect picklist) from a list of lets say 20 fields, now on the next screen I want to show those selected fields with respective input text boxes and then user will fill this form and record gets saved. How can I achieve this as I am unable to pass multiple selected values from one screen to next screen.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of writing, this is not possible. The only thing that might be possible is creating a collection of variables, looping over these variables and show a screen for each instance, representing a choice from the multiselect picklist. Than you can put input text boxes on each screen. This means that when a user chooses 10 options, he will see 10 screens, which is not very neat.

I would build a custom page for this. It is probably faster and might even be better maintainable.